# How do I configure a Shared Load Balancer with ElasticBeanstalk using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an ElasticBeanstalk application with 3 environments and would like to use a shared load balancer instead one per environment. Using Terraform I have created the load balancer and configured ElasticBeanstalk to use it. ElasticBeanstalk creates the target group but I am unable to create a listener because ElasticBeanstalk doesn't appear to expose the target group ARN.

I have something very similar to the following so far...

```
resource "aws_lb" "main" {
  name               = "myloadbalancer"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.loadbalancer.id]
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.public1.id, aws_subnet.public2.id, aws_subnet.public3.id]
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "main" {
  name = "myapp"
}

# I have 3 seperate environments ("one", "two", "three" in this example)
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "one" {
  name                = "one"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.main.name
  ...
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
    name      = "LoadBalancerIsShared"
    value     = true
  }
  settings {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:loadbalancer"
    name      = "SharedLoadBalancer"
    value     = aws_lb.main.arn
  }
  ...
}
```

My expectation is to create a listener with a rule that directs traffic for `one.<domain>` to the target group for the environment named "one", etc